# How to Retrieve All Active Inventories from All tenants and companies to one custom screen selector in Acumatica?

Tags: c#, acumatica

How to Retrieve All Active Inventories from All tenants and companies to one custom screen selector in Acumatica??

In ISV Solution I am trying this. How to approach this scenario

Comment: On the surface, the only way I know to do this is via the CompanyMask, although I have not done it.  I'm interested in this as well... following.

Comment: Products are shared between companies in the same tenant, correct?  Isn't the purpose of tenants to divide information? I'm trying to think of a use-case when it would be a good idea to be able to select all inventory from every tenant.  Most inventory stuff is tied to financials, and if financials are separate, would not the usefulness be at least severely limited?

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:** What you are asking appears to venture into a use case that is contrary to a foundational design element of Acumatica ERP - isolation of tenants within a single database.  While I have a similar use case in mind in which I need to do the same, use of any of these suggestions should be weighed seriously against your business requirements and operating constraints.*

After discussion with some Acumatica Developer MVP's and Acumatica staff, there is no SUPPORTED method for doing this directly with tables already containing a CompanyID field.  However, here are a few possible ways to achieve your desired results.

1. Create alternate SQL Tables / Acumatica DAC's without CompanyID and CompanyMask so that the data can be shared.  This will require keeping the supplemental table data in sync.
2. UNSUPPORTED *(This will fail an ISV Certification)* - Create a SQL view that excludes CompanyID and CompanyMask and an Acumatica DAC for that view.  This will allow visibility to the data, regardless of tenant, without having to create or maintain duplicate data.  Again, I was advised strongly against this approach in the same statement of it being *possible*.
3. Use an alternative tool to access the data in the SQL database if you have direct access to the database.  This tool would have to access the database in a way completely independently of PXData so that all database queries do not automatically receive the "CompanyID = X" in the where clause.
4. It was mentioned that you might do something with impersonating other users, but I don't have any experience with that.  I'm not sure if it would allow cross-tenant data access, but I don't believe it would allow viewing more than 1 tenant even if it does let you view another tenant at all.

My understanding is that the first option is the preferred method to stay within Acumatica in a supported way.  The third option could be valid if you already use other analytics tools like Cognos.